# RadioButton.setText() is not displaying the text

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I am creating RadioButtons and adding them to RadioGroup dynamically.
But the text for the RadioButtons are not showing on the screen when I run the application.

This is my code for RadioButtons

```
else if ((items.get(i).toString()).equals("rad")) {
                RadioGroup bg = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
                int child=0;
                for (int h = textlen; h < text.size(); textlen++) {

                    if (text.get(textlen).contains("(")) {

                        s = text.get(textlen).replace("(", "");

                        if (s.contains(")"))
                            s = s.replace(")", "");

                    } else if (text.get(textlen).contains(")")) {
                        s = text.get(textlen).replace(")", "");
                    } else
                        s = text.get(textlen);

                    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    bg.addView(radioButton);
                    // / radioButton.setName("rbt");
                    if (s.contains("{on}")) {
                    //  radioButton.setSelected(true);
                        radioButton.setChecked(true);
                        s = s.replace("{on}", "");
                    } else {
                        radioButton.setChecked(false);
                        s = s.replace("{of}", "");
                    }
                    //((RadioButton)bg.getChildAt(child)).setText(s);
                    //child++;

                    radioButton.setText(s);

                    String c = text.get(textlen).substring(
                            text.get(textlen).length() - 1);
                    if (c.equals(")")) {
                        textlen++;
                        break;
                    }



                }

                layout.addView(bg);
            }
```

When I debug the code I can see that the text is added to RadioGropus children

But on running the application the text is not visible.
Can any one please detect the issue.
Thanks Alot

Comment: try setting the text first and then use `bg.addView(radioButton);` also assign an id to the radiobutton by using `setId()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add

```
setLayoutParams(params);
```

for both RadioButton as well as RadioGroup.

Where

```
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the text color and your text appears.
By default the text color is white, n this was the problem in my case

Comment: that could be one, may be. But not in my Case. But thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens a lot of time because ample amount of room is not allocated to the widgets and they are unable to display the text though it is there. If the debugger is showing the text, the code is fine...check the XML and assign proper space to the widgets. Try assigning harcoded text to clarify.

Comment: Thanks Alot for your answer. But I have no xml I am generating the whole layout in java.How can I assign proper spaces as I am using linerlayout and not giving any space.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot

Comment: Of the radiobuttons in the app

Comment: as you can see above, there are radio buttons but with no text :(

Comment: Try setting height and width dynamically when you are creating your radio button

Comment: Any specific reason for desiginig layout using Java and not XML?

Comment: yeah because I have to generate the layout according to a specific string received from server after user login. But if I use xml I cant create the form while the app is running

Comment: As @Rohit5k2 suggested, have you tried setting height and width dynamically?

Comment: "I have to generate the layout according to a specific string received from server after user login" - you can do this by designing layout in XML also. I would strictly suggest you to design layout in XML for the best result.

Comment: Aren't you familiar with XML?

Comment: I am. But we have to create xml before running the code. We cant do that if(String.equals(TextFiled)){  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username" >
    </EditText>} else{.............}